# format r(repr) of print in python3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, format

```
>>>print('You say:{0:r}'.format("i love you"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    print('You say:{0:r}'.format("i love you"))
ValueError: Unknown format code 'r' for object of type 'str'
```

I just use `%r(repr())` in python2, and it should work in python3.5. Why is it?

Besides, what format should I use?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

What you are looking for is called conversion flag. And that should be specified like this

```
>>> print('you say:{0!r}'.format("i love you"))
you say:'i love you'
```

Quoting Python 3's [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax),

> Three conversion flags are currently supported: `'!s'` which calls `str()` on the value, `'!r'` which calls `repr()` and `'!a'` which calls `ascii()`.

Please note that, Python 2 supports only `!s` and `!r`. As per the Python 2's [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec),

> Two conversion flags are currently supported: `'!s'` which calls `str()` on the value, and `'!r'` which calls `repr()`.

---

In Python 2, you might have done something like

```
>>> 'you say: %r' % "i love you"
"you say: 'i love you'"
```

But even in Python 2 (also in Python 3), you can write the same with `!r` with `format`, like this

```
>>> 'you say: {!r}'.format("i love you")
"you say: 'i love you'"
```

Quoting example from [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples),

> Replacing `%s` and `%r`:
>
> ```
> >>> "repr() shows quotes: {!r}; str() doesn't: {!s}".format('test1', 'test2')
> "repr() shows quotes: 'test1'; str() doesn't: test2"
> ```

Answer (score 8):

In python3's f-string formatting, you can also use:

```
print(f"You say:{'i love you'!r}")
You say:'i love you'
print(f'You say:{"i love you"!r}')
You say:'i love you'
```

Noted that both return 'i love you' enclosed in single-quotes.